# Want to reverse the order of click events attached to one element in jquery

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have one scenario where I want to change order of click events attached to one element. I am using jquery 1.3.2, I used following code to reverse the order of events

```
$("#button").bind('click',first);

var foo = $.data( $('#button').get(0), 'events' ).click;
var firstHandler;
$.each( foo, function(i,defination) {
    firstHandler = defination;
    $('#button').unbind('click', defination);
});

$("#button").bind('click',second);
$("#button").bind('click',firstHandler);

function first() { alert("first"); };
function second() { alert("second"); };
```

This code works well in all other browsers(FF, IE, Safari) but not working as expected in Chrome. Here is a online version of my code please have a look [Working code at Online Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKRR8/18/)

Can Anybody guide me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse clicks by taking the `.clicks` array, copying it before removing it, unbinding the clicks, then re-binding in the reverse order, like this:

```
var clicks = $('#button').data('events').click.slice();
var button = $('#button').unbind('click');
$.each(clicks.reverse(), function() {
    button.click(this);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yqSNn/).  Or, a bit more generic, let's make it a plugin:

```
$.fn.reverseHandlers = function(eventType) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var handlers = $.data(this, 'events')[eventType].slice();
    var elem = $(this).unbind(eventType);
    $.each(handlers.reverse(), function() {
      elem.bind(eventType, this.handler);
    });    
  });
};
```

[You can test that format here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yqSNn/1/), just just call it by: `$("#button").reverseHandlers("click");`

**Note for jQuery 1.3.x users**: the event structure was formatted differently prior to 1.4+, if anyone needs a version that works with 1.3.x please comment here and I'll add it.

Comment: Hi Nick, Your code works well with 1.4+ But I am more interested in code which will run with jQuery 1.3.2. Can you please comment it here ?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, `.data('events')` is no longer available, and sadly this solution no longer works. https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#data-quot-events-quot-